# Programmatically show the keyboard on iPhone app

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, keyboard

I have a view with only one UITextView that is used to enter a value. I want that when the view shows, the textview becomes the first responder (that's the easy part) and also the default keyboard shows up. I tried searching for this in speca but to no avail. There are many posts on how to *dismiss* the keyboard, but what I want is to *show* the keyboard w/o waiting for user to touch my textview.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just setting the text field to firstResponder should do the trick.

Inside your `-viewDidLoad`:

```
[myTextField becomeFirstResponder];
```

Comment: Damn, I was sending my message to the cell holding the textview, not to the textview itself. ty